# R: dplyr can't filter() certain character

Tags: r

The data (named "metInfo") I use is provided here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGtOBOzD-K4iEpDUyeb9e5b_D7afr7Fk/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, in the `metInfo %>% pull(rtc) %>% unique` has two levels

```
> library(dplyr)
> load("metInfo.RData")
> metInfo %>% pull(rtc) %>% unique
[1] RTC  nRTC
Levels: nRTC RTC
```

And the strange part is that I can `metInfo %>% filter(rtc == "RTC")` but not `metInfo %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")`.
"RTC"

```
> metInfo %>% filter(rtc == "RTC")
# A tibble: 318 x 3
# Groups:   Compound_Name [318]
   peak_ID   rtc   Compound_Name                                     
   <chr>     <fct> <chr>                                             
 1 PP_012966 RTC   Uric acid                                         
 2 PP_010664 RTC   Norleucine                                       
 3 PP_011736 RTC   L-Tryptophan                                     
 4 PP_012298 RTC   O-Acetyl-L-carnitine                             
 5 PP_010311 RTC   Betaine | 5-Aminopentanoic acid                   
 6 PP_012958 RTC   L-Tyrosine | 3-Amino-3-(4-hydroxyphenyl)propanoate
 7 PP_011703 RTC   L-Leucine | L-Isoleucine                         
 8 PP_010688 RTC   Cycloleucine | (S)-Piperidine-2-carboxylic acid   
 9 PN_006454 RTC   Glycochenodeoxycholic acid                       
10 PP_011268 RTC   L-Histidine                                       
# ... with 308 more rows
```

"nRTC"

```
> metInfo %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# Groups:   Compound_Name [0]
# ... with 3 variables: peak_ID <chr>, rtc <fct>, Compound_Name <chr>
```

However, using R base filtering function, it returns what I want:

```
> metInfo[metInfo$rtc == "nRTC",]
# A tibble: 344 x 3
# Groups:   Compound_Name [344]
   peak_ID   rtc   Compound_Name                                                                                                                               
   <chr>     <fct> <chr>                                                                                                                                       
 1 PP_011268 nRTC  L-Histidine                                                                                                                                 
 2 PP_011695 nRTC  L-Kynurenine                                                                                                                               
 3 PN_008846 nRTC  Decanedioic acid                                                                                                                           
 4 PP_011647 nRTC  L-Glutamic acid                                                                                                                             
 5 PN_005920 nRTC  Azelaic acid                                                                                                                               
 6 PP_010311 nRTC  Betaine | 5-Aminopentanoic acid                                                                                                             
 7 PN_001048 nRTC  [(3aS,4S,5S,6E,10E,11aR)-6-formyl-5-methoxy-10-methyl-3-methylidene-2-oxo-3a,4,5,8,9,11a-hexahydrocyclodeca[b]furan-4-yl] 2-methylpropanoate
 8 PP_010704 nRTC  Pyroglutamic acid                                                                                                                           
 9 PN_007538 nRTC  Octanedioic acid                                                                                                                           
10 PP_012958 nRTC  L-Tyrosine | 3-Amino-3-(4-hydroxyphenyl)propanoate                                                                                         
# ... with 334 more rows
```

Strange enough, I tried to create a data.frame to see if this is due to `"n"` problem such as `"\n"` for something, but it turns out that this is not the case:
No problem with "nRTC"

```
haha <- data.frame(a =c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), b = c("RTC", "RTC", "RTC", "nRTC", "nRTC", "nRTC")) %>% as.tbl()
> haha %>% filter(b == "nRTC")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a     b   
  <fct> <fct>
1 D     nRTC
2 E     nRTC
3 F     nRTC
```

Nor "RTC"

```
> haha %>% filter(b == "RTC")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a     b   
  <fct> <fct>
1 A     RTC 
2 B     RTC 
3 C     RTC
```

Nor "nRTC" with R base

```
> haha[haha$b == "nRTC", ]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a     b   
  <fct> <fct>
1 D     nRTC
2 E     nRTC
3 F     nRTC
```

This is the structure of `metInfo$rtc`

```
> dput(metInfo$rtc)
structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("nRTC", "RTC"
), class = "factor")
```

Is anything wrong with the data structure?

Comment: Can you paste the output of  `dput(metInfo)` into the question?

Comment: There has to be a problem with the characters in 'nRTC'...  But since I cant access google drives I can't tell for sure... It would be more appropriate to create a minimal reproducible example data set (as suggested by @IceCreamToucan and in the header of stackoverflows R page) than to require people to access some 3rd party servers to help you....

Comment: Hi， I've edited the post, please check

Comment: @dario Hi, I tried to create a minimal example as shown in `haha` example, and didn't have problem, so I am not sure if this is a character-specified problem or something else

Comment: The issue is not reproducible for me with the data you posted. Adding that vector to a data.frame and running `metInfo %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")` works fine for me

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you are having with the information you supplied. I'd suggest to start in a fresh R session and create the **smallest** data set that reproduces your problem (this data set could consist of only 2 rows and 2 columns as far as I can tell, no need to publish all 662 rows ;) EDIT: To be more concrete: Take your original data and start removing columns and  rows, while checking of the problem persists) You can then add the output of this minimal data set to your original question...

Comment: This is very strange because I reproduced in three different machines (2 Linux and 1 Windows) and got the same result, I will take @dario's advice to see if I can produce a minimal `metInfo` by selected some random rows

Comment: Hi again, I managed to get `nRTC` by `metInfo %>% as.data.frame() %>% as.tbl() %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")`, this is strange though, do you guys have any idea why this behaves like this? Please note that even `metInfo %>% as.tbl() %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")` doesn't work but works for `metInfo %>% as.tbl() %>% filter(rtc == "RTC")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `metInfo` is a `grouped_df`

```
> class(metInfo)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Thus just `ungroup()` the `metInfo`

```
> metInfo %>% ungroup %>% filter(rtc == "nRTC")
# A tibble: 344 x 3
   peak_ID   rtc   Compound_Name                                                                                                                               
   <chr>     <fct> <chr>                                                                                                                                       
 1 PP_011268 nRTC  L-Histidine                                                                                                                                 
 2 PP_011695 nRTC  L-Kynurenine                                                                                                                                
 3 PN_008846 nRTC  Decanedioic acid                                                                                                                            
 4 PP_011647 nRTC  L-Glutamic acid                                                                                                                             
 5 PN_005920 nRTC  Azelaic acid                                                                                                                                
 6 PP_010311 nRTC  Betaine | 5-Aminopentanoic acid                                                                                                             
 7 PN_001048 nRTC  [(3aS,4S,5S,6E,10E,11aR)-6-formyl-5-methoxy-10-methyl-3-methylidene-2-oxo-3a,4,5,8,9,11a-hexahydrocyclodeca[b]furan-4-yl] 2-methylpropanoate
 8 PP_010704 nRTC  Pyroglutamic acid                                                                                                                           
 9 PN_007538 nRTC  Octanedioic acid                                                                                                                            
10 PP_012958 nRTC  L-Tyrosine | 3-Amino-3-(4-hydroxyphenyl)propanoate                                                                                          
# ... with 334 more rows
```